# Finding the furthest point on an arc from a line segment

Tags: geometry, optimization

Given

- a circular arc described by three points: $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$
- a line segment described by two points: $B_1$ and $B_2$

how could I determine the **maximum** distance between any point on the arc and its corresponding **closest** point on the line segment?

Comment: If you've learnt calculus then that is the way to go.

Comment: A potentially relevant concept is that of the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

Comment: @madnessweasley Yes but people might be interested only in d_arc = Max({ Distance(P, arc) | P in segment }) or only in d_segment = Max({ Distance(P, segment) | P in arc } ), whereas the Hausdorff distance is Max(d_arc, d_segment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct the midline perpendicular to $A_1A_2$ as well that of $A_2A_3$. These will intersect in $M$. Then construct the perpendicular from $M$ wrt. the line $B_1B_2$. Finally you will have to take on that very line just the same distance as between $A_1$ and $M$. This will determine that farthest point $C$ of the arc. Now you just have to consider the distance between that point $C$ and the line $B_1B_2$.

--- rk

Comment: I do not follow you on the step: "Finally you will have to take on that very line just the same distance as between A1 and M"

Comment: If $B_1B_2$ runs through $M$, then the searched value clearly is the afore derived radius. Else we have to construct the perpendicular from $M$ onto that line. Its intersection with the circle would be $C_1$ resp. $C_2$. One of them is farer from the line by assumption. Call that one $C$.

Comment: That's clearer, thanks. Also I believe you still have to check 2 extremities if you want d_arc or d_segment (defined in my comment on the question) or 4 extremities for the Hausdorff distance.

Comment: My answers were dealing with the maximum only. Clearly the minimum can be achieved along the same lines. Simply use the other $C_i$.